# php artisan commands stop working after composer update in laravel 5.1

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I was adding the html Collective class by updating composer.json with

```
"require": {
"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

then I run composer update command as per the instructions from `https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html` first it throws a

```
Fetal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\wamp\www\laravel3\laravel\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

and some errors about artisan and now artisan commands are not working, even I have tried new installation of laravel.

Comment: did you try running `php artisan dump-autoload` after the update?

Comment: yes i did but it says [Sympfony\Component\Debut\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Did you see any errors during composer update? You can also try `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: yes it happens only after doing composer update, on composer update it gives the Fetal error the one I show above in my question.

Comment: and on php artisan clear-compiled it also showing [Sympfony\Component...] error the one i mention in our discussion

Comment: Remove the HTML collective from the app.php before running dumpautoload, then add it again after installed by composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use form and html in blade template I was trying to install Collective class using the instructions of https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html site, as per instructions I put `"require": { "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*" }` into composer.json and then I ran composer update in command line which didn't update my composer, instead  php artisan commands stop working and I receive different errors and exceptions, to solve those issues I struggle with commands such as `composer update --no-scripts, php artisan clear-compiled, composer dump-autoload etc.` which didn't solve the issue at all. Then I just type following command in command line: `composer require "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"`, it update composer.json file automatically, after this process I just add providers and aliases into `config/app.php`, and now every thing works normal.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I suspect that the composer is not updated properly. Try doing composer update now with 
`composer update --no-scripts`
followed by,

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: followed by means I should type all in one time          composer update --no-scripts php artisan clear-compiled composer dump-autoload

Comment: no, run them serially and individually in the order I've written.

Comment: I am very confused because yesterday I tried composer update --no-scripts,  it updated composer very well but still the php artisan commands was not working

Comment: strange! you can also try deleting `composer.lock` file and then run `composer install`. But for me the `composer update --no-scripts` has solved the problem

Comment: ok I am trying that it will take may be 5 minutes, are you still with me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97255/discussion-between-mohsin-and-vishal-sh).

Answer (score 0):

Try composer installation again then update.

```
composer install
composer update
composer dumpautoload -o
```

This happens when an update is not completed successfully.